# How to display a UITableView when UISearch is clicked.

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uilabel, uisearchbar

I am creating an app and need the user to select an activity.  I want them to be able to search through the activities as there are a lot in the list.  I want to just have a search bar on the main view,(with placeholder text that says select activity.)  When they click in the search bar, I want a table view to appear with the list of activities, and then I want them to be able to search the table view.  I know how to do the search features of the search bar but I don't know how to make it pull up the table view, or how to dismiss the table view after they select one.  And I want it to display the name of the activity in a label after it is dismissed. Any suggestions will help.

Thanks!

Comment: have you considered instantiating the UITableView via code and adding it to your view hierarchy via addSubview?  Then later removing it view removeSubview?

Comment: @CSmith I am new to programming, so no. I am mainly just looking for the easiest way to do this...Could you provide some sample code or more information?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `UISearchDisplayController` it makes things much easier.
It manage the second `UITableView` so you don't need to do it yourself.
To dismiss the search table view when ever you want, call - `[mySearchController setActive:NO];`

Take a look at those tutorials

[Implementing A Basic Search with UISearchDisplayController and Interface Builder](http://ygamretuta.me/2011/08/10/ios-implementing-a-basic-search-uisearchdisplaycontroller-and-interface-builder/)

[UISearchDisplayController with NSPredicate](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-uisearchdisplaycontroller-with-nspredicate/)